# KnockoutJS - Mapping and Extenders

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to implement some kind of undo feature in my project using KnockoutJS. For this purpose, I'm using this extender:

```
ko.extenders.trackChange = function (target, track) {
    if (track) {
        target.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
        target.originalValue = target();
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {

            // Push to "states" array a JS representation of the viewModel
            // so I can get a stack of changes
            states.push(ko.toJS(track.myViewModel));

            target.isDirty(newValue != target.originalValue);               
            target.originalValue = newValue;

        });
    }
    return target;
};
```

Then I apply the extender to an object into the viewModel:

```
this.myViewModel = {
    label: ko.observable("Label").extend({ trackChange: this });
}
```

And when I want to undo an action, I do this:

```
ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(states[statesPointer]));
```

This is ok in order to get the old values, but the extend function in the observable is lost so new changes are not saved in the "states" stack.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Elian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not create new model instance performing *undo* op, but **just update** observable properties of existing model:

```
// you do:
// ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(states[statesPointer]));

// I would do:
ko.mapping.fromJS(states[statesPointer], myViewModel);
```

Looks like your `myViewModel` has own context, so you have to modify my code to get correct ref to the model.

Comment: That did the trick, but I had to create the viewModel with mapping:
    this.myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({
        label: ko.observable("Label").extend({ trackChange: this });
    }
Is that ok?

Comment: Also, when I do the mapping, the trackChange extender stops working.

Comment: You can create the object with `mapping` plugin first and apply the extender to its props later. As a result you will get the object which can be *updated* with the method mentioned in my answer; extender should work after update too. You can see my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCXeV/

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo. I tried to replicate the scenario but the extender is still missing after the update. Could you check this fiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/AF494/1/